# When did it become customary to eschew gender pronouns in scientific essays?

Tags: pronouns, writing-style, science

So, anyone who's written a scientific essay knows that the use of he/she/him/her, etc are frowned-upon (except where necessary)

But where does this come from? When did it achieve (near) consensus? When were the guidelines first written by a major academic body?

Comment: Please give an example of what you mean. Are you talking about pronouns with specific or nonspecific referents?

Comment: Like, if you were writing a review article, you'd be expected to say "in Example (1998) it was found that", rather than "in his/her study, Example (1998) found that". We're expected to erase the scientists (including ourselves) and just leave the sexless, disembodied science. When did that become a thing?

Comment: It's been a popular trend since the 60's (in the US). By trend I mean that some of it happened before the 60's, but since then it has been more obvious, but not an overnight change. I wonder what the current style guides say, if they mention it at all (I'm pretty sure that they encourage or at least allow a singular 'they'.

Comment: “Example (1998) finds that…” is perfectly common; but in my experience, most with the humanities, so is “Example (1998) finds that…, but her analysis is based on…” and such things. It may be customary in some fields to avoid gendered pronouns when referring to authors (oneself or others), but it certainly isn’t universal.

Comment: The question was asked before [[active vs passive voice in lab reports and history of scientific usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186685/active-vs-passive-voice-in-lab-reports-and-history-of-scientific-usage)] and didn't receive an accepted answer.

Comment: This is a question of history and requires comparison of sources. You should provide own research to help answer the question. Also, I am not sure whether the question is directed at passive vs active voice or avoidance of gendering. The latter might have started later and it might boost the former.

Comment: I'm specifically concerned with gender (as per the title) but I acknowledge there's some overlap between that and the active/passive voice. Also, if I could answer my own question, I wouldn't be here...

Comment: Please do not use unjustified and unnecessary generalizations like "anyone who has written a scieintific essay knows". I personally have set scientific essays to students for years and would encourage the use of 'he' as a common gender singular pronoun, hating the use of 'they' in the singular. I suspect most students nowadays self-censor. You need to specify the geographical and cultural context if this your personal experience. I am in Britain.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the poster is referring to undergraduate science education in universities in the USA. I am a British scientist, but from reading  general science news in journals like *Nature* I am not aware of a historic event involving “guidelines… written by a major academic body” on the use of ‘he/she’. I imagine that in today’s climate this would be covered by general sexual discrimination guidelines and, in any case, there is probably widespread cultural conformism or self-censoring. I, for one, would regard an edict on what words I or my students were allowed to use as an assault on academic freedom.

However, the question can be interpreted in a more general sense as:

> “When did the change of attitude *against* the use of ‘he’ to cover individuals of both sexes appear in English-speaking academic science?”

The answer is, of course,

> 1984

(or thereabouts).

I have a cutting in my possession, taken from [*Nature* **309**, 387 (1984)](http://www.nature.com.ezproxy.lib.gla.ac.uk/nature/journal/v309/n5967/pdf/309387b0.pdf) which accompanied a piece on the (British) Dunstan Committee Report on artificial insemination etc. As this is not freely available, I reproduce an edited version below:

> **Liberation Language**
>
> The introduction to the Dunstan report by Professor John Ziman… includes the following explanation of a now-unfashionable usage:
>
> “The report is written in English, a language which has a common gender
>   for statements applying to masculine and feminine, male and female,
>   without distinction. Sometimes the grammatical form of the common
>   gender and masculine coincide, but that is no impediment to its use.
>   We have employed this grammatical facility because it yields a prose
>   less cluttered and more elegant, and as readable.”

Answer (score 0):

The 17th edition of the Chicago Manual of Style indeed addresses the singular they (http://cmosshoptalk.com/2017/04/03/chicago-style-for-the-singular-they/) but points out it is to be used when you don't know the gender of the person you're referring to to avoid the "generic he." If you can identify the authors, I would suggest following Janus's example from the humanities.

Comment: Please include the example in your answer. Comments might be deleted, or there may get lost in a sea of comments, users change their monikers or delete their accounts, and then nobody would understand who – Janus Bahs Jacquet is or what you are referring to. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Part of the definition of the scientific method is that the use of *he/she/him/her, etc* are not just frowned-upon, but forbidden except where necessary.

*Igor did this* or *Dr Frankenstein did that* might be wholly *accurate*, but it's not *repeatable* in any other laboratory.

The required form is *the switch was thrown* and not even *the switch was thrown by Dr F…* could be acceptable, unless the point of the report was to hi-light a different result when the switch was thrown by Dr F than by Igor or anyone else.

Comment: You seem to think that merely by the very nature of science, true scientists will leave out all pronouns in scientific publications. This isn't correct. Let me quote from Isaac Newton: *"Then I looked through the Prism upon the hole, and turning the Prism to and fro about its Axis, to make the Image of the Hole ascend and descend, when between its two contrary Motions it seemed Stationary, I stopp'd the Prism, that the Refractions of both sides of the refracting Angle might be equal to each other, as in the former Experiment."*

Comment: Writing entirely in a passive style is considered too old-fashioned in some scientific publications now.

Comment: Yes, Simon; of course it is and there have always been those who fancy form over function, and there has always been a difference between what is and is not capable of being replicated…

How much d'you bet the vast majority of those who consider pains-taking less respectable were taught by modern teachers with plenty of theoretical training and no relevant experience?

Comment: "Part of the definition of the scientific method…" Really? Your source for this bizarre assertion?

Comment: Uh… the most basic secondary school science, David. I’m sorry and 50 years ago, every child of 11 was taught this. Are there members over, say, age 50 who don’t remember that?
In Peter's example, consider what 'science' meant in Newton's day.
In Simon's, ask whether the slickest style could ever matter as much as strict substance?
This is supposed to be axiomatic, needing no formal definition.
The real question, sadly, is when did it stop being obvious…

Comment: I wonder what schools you are thinking of where children were “taught the scientific method”. I went to an old-fashioned English Grammar school over 50 years ago and never encountered the phrase. Perhaps it was too modern — we learned by doing. But I really think you misunderstand the poster’s concern, which is whether one uses 'he' or 'he/she' or 'they' in circumstances where one is referring to a single human individual whose sex is immaterial to the scientific argument.

Comment: David, if you’re saying you weren’t *taught the scientific method* does that mean it wasn’t in the curriculum; you don’t remember noticing; my teachers threw in something extra?

Concern about pronouns belongs to the PC gender argument; not to science.

Why is it hard to see if *Igor used his* or *Igora used her* (relevant qualities or resources) to do this or that, it cannot be replicated by half the population.

Once upon a time that seemed like nonsense but please list some modern chemists who seriously believe hormones, pheromones or Lord-knows-what can’t affect anything?

Comment: @Robbie: if you don't think Newton was a true scientist, maybe you could tell me who would qualify. The way we write up science is a social costruct. In fact, you admit this yourself by saying "every child of 11 was **taught this.** The OP's question is: when did that social construct change so as to bar 3rd person pronouns?

Comment: Did you notice not only that Newton was an alchemist and astrologer but that before him, there were no "true scientists" in any modern sense?

Then broadly no, by no modern means could Newton be considered "a true scientist…", not even had he invented "our" scientific method. 

More importantly, Daniel said most that needed to be said while Janus speaks of reviews, not the essays in question. Why does the idea that Igor did this or Dr Frankenstein did that might be wholly accurate, but neither is repeatable in any other laboratory not sit well with you?

Comment: @Robbie: if you don't believe that Isaac Newton was a true scientist, how about Louis Pasteur? "We took a double-necked flask, of three litres (five pints) capacity, one of the tubes being curved and forming an escape for the gas; the other one, on the right hand side (Fig. 1), being furnished with a glass tap. We filled this flask with pure yeast water, sweetened with 5 per cent, of sugar candy, the flask being so full that there was not the least trace of air remaining above the tap or in the escape tube ..." This idea of not using pronouns is a social construct.

Comment: @PeterShor Sorry and while I have no idea why anyone might see not using pronouns as a "social construct", that's still beside the point. I have no interest in "gender" in cases like this; merely in "pronouns"… and you miss the point.

Newton is respected for his achievements but which university today do you think would admit a student with his views?

Length lends little to you Pasteur example and why can you not explain how, exactly, his "we" could be replicated anywhere else?